# Flask + SqlAlchemy delete database entries

Tags: python, mysql, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I have to delete database entries conditionally and I couldn't figure out as the form is asking for correct parameters posted in uri. I can delete entries in shell with same code but not in view. Following is the view and form:

```
@app.route('/cancelannualsub/<int:student_id>', methods=['DELETE'])
def cancel_yearly_rec(student_id):

    if not user_authorized():
        return redirect('/')

    user = get_profile_data(session['auth_token'])
    profile_data = user['StudentProfile']

    pkg = Package.query.filter_by(student_id=profile_data.id).first_or_404()

    if request.method=='POST':
        try:
            pkg = Package()
            dbase.session.delete(pkg)
            flash('Package deleted successfully.')
            dbase.session.commit()
        except:
            pass 


        return redirect('plans')
    return render_template('profile/cancel/cancel.html')
```

Form:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('cancel_yearly_rec', student_id=***can't render value here***) }}" method='post'>
                    <input type='hidden' name='_method' value='DELETE'
                    <input class='btn' type="submit" value="Cancel" />
                </form>
```

I am trying different things from stackoverflow examples. Please assist if I am doing something wrong or if there is a better way to do it.

Comment: you have a typo here `pkg = Pacakge()` , `pacakge` -> `package`

Comment: This isn't error in original code...I checked. Now what do I add in form for student_id="what to add here".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wasn't using proper formatting to render model objects inside try block.

It supposed to be something like:

```
mymodel = Model.query.filter_by(variable=some_field_data).first_or_404()
dbase.session.delete(mymodel)
dbase.session.commit()
```

For readers don't get confused with "dbase" because I made this import like:
from app import `db` as `dbase`
You can import it simply by:

```
from app import db
```

or add "`as anything`".
Then you reference anything in rest of your file where you've made import.